# Interfacing std compatibility to opaque data with external evaluation dispatch

Tags: c++, algorithm, iterator, std, opaque-pointers

I am receiving managed data in a low level `{ void * data; uint stride, count; }` format. I can read, write and swap data items, but not to add or remove / resize / reallocate. There's enough information to iterate and random access, but no type info for dereferencing. All opaque items  can be mem copied and moved trivially.

Is it possible in modern C++ to facilitate std compatibility for such a data format, omitting the dereferencing interface, and delegating the evaluation to an external context? Something like:

```
std::sort(OpaqueFirst, OpaqueLast, [](Opaque a, Opaque b){ return handle(a, b); });
```

Comment: You can use boost transform iterator to make this possible.

Comment: I removed my comment. Using an existing iterator from boost is much better than creating one from scratch.

Comment: That seems a bit too over-engineered for my needs, and bringing in a dependency, seems like a dummy byte deref might do the trick, quick and dirty. The opaque references are already working on byte grain for indexing anyway.

Comment: Ok, if not bringing in boost (or part of boost) for it, you'll have to write your own I guess. Is `stride` something you know at compile time or will that pop up in runtime? If it's at runtime, are there any lower and higher limits of what it can be?

Comment: It is a mixed usage scenario, there's gonna be inline implementations via lambdas, dynamic function calls and even evaluation by an interpreter, for the former the stride is usually a compile time constant, for the rest the stride will be mostly a runtime dynamic value. The stride is a 32 bit unsigned integer, typically it won't be anywhere the upper limits. The logical addressing scheme is de-facto 64 bit - split into up to 32 bit item count and up to 32bit item size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is to create a type that **refers** to one of your subarrays and define `swap` to actually swap their contents:

```
struct buffer {std::span<std::byte> s;};  // but see below

void swap(const buffer &a,const buffer &b) {
  assert(a.s.size()==b.s.size());
  auto i=b.s.begin();
  for(auto &x : a.s) std::swap(x,*i++);
}
```

Then we merely have to create a lazy range of such objects, which is easy with `std::views::transform` wrapped around `std::views::iota`, and write the trivial comparator from the question:

```
struct array { void * data; uint stride, count; };

void sort(const array &a,bool lt(const void*,const void*)) {
  std::ranges::sort
    (std::views::transform
     (std::views::iota(uint(),a.count),
      [&](uint i)
      {return buffer{{static_cast<std::byte*>(a.data)+a.stride*i,a.stride}};}),
     [&](const buffer &x,const buffer &y) {return lt(x.s.data(),y.s.data());});
}
```

Unfortunately, `sort` demands to be able to **move** range elements into temporary variables, not just swap them.  That requires a rather more complicated wrapper type that can actually **own** the data temporarily, which in turn requires dynamic allocation since `array::stride` isn't a constant:

```
struct buffer {
  std::unique_ptr<std::byte[]> u;
  std::span<std::byte> s;

  buffer(std::span<std::byte> s) : s(s) {}
  buffer(buffer &&b) noexcept {
    if(b.u) u=std::move(b.u);
    else {
      u=std::make_unique<std::byte[]>(b.s.size());
      std::ranges::copy(b.s,u.get());
      s={u.get(),b.s.size()};
    }
  }

  void operator=(const buffer &b) const noexcept;
  buffer& operator=(const buffer &b) noexcept {
    assert(s.size()==b.s.size());
    std::ranges::copy(b.s,s.begin());
    return *this;
  }
};
```

Retaining our custom `swap` avoids using such allocations for every element swap, so the performance isn't terrible.  The unimplemented `operator=(…) const` is necessary to convince the library that `buffer` is a **proxy** type that should support sorting via prvalues.

A [complete example](https://www.godbolt.org/z/fWPYs3dcx) with the full `buffer` type exists on Compiler Explorer.

Comment: On an unrelated note - your spacebar ok? That much whitespace conservatism does not stack well on top of std::exceeding::amount::of<verbosity>(); readability wise.

Comment: The very high demand for whitespace has unfortunately driven it out of my price range in all but cases of the most dire need.  Obviously the static buffer can work, although then you can’t sort in parallel (if that matters).

Comment: I have a sub question here, in the case of something like lower bounds, which doesn't go through all elements, only the transformations of the probed elements will actually be calculated, is that right?